# Does the TI CC2540 support Bluetooth High Speed protocol?

Tags: bluetooth, iphone, high-speed

The Bluetooth High Speed (HS) protocol is included in the Bluetooth 4.0 spec, but I can't find whether or not standard Bluetooth 4.0 modules such as the [TI CC2540](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540&DCMP=LowPowerRFICs+Other&HQS=Other+OT+cc2540) support the high speed part of the spec.  Most of them focus on the "low energy" feature of the spec.  Are there any modules that support the "high speed" protocol?  How would I find out?

In addition, do Bluetooth 4.0 devices such as the iPhone 4S support the "high speed" part of the Bluetooth 4.0 spec?

Comment: Ask your TI representative or distributor's FAE

Comment: Regarding the CC2540 module, I would say that it does not support the high speed protocol. The low energy protocol is backwards compatible with previous bluetooth specs, whereas the High Speed protocol is an extension to the previous spec. I would look for modules that support 4.0+2.1 etc as these modules are more likely to support the high speed protocol.

Comment: I thought the High Speed protocol was included in the 4.0 spec? (Not as an extension.)

Comment: @tuxfool: Bluetooth LE is *NOT* compatible with "old" (aka Classic) Bluetooth, it has different PHY (modulation), different MAC, different link layer. That's what allowed to make it "Low Energy" - breaking compatibility with Bluetooth Classic the power hog. The fact that there're chips which support both LE and Classic is different matter. There're chips which support only LE (and those are the ones which are really low-power).

Comment: Actually the High Speed is actually done using WiFi as the Backbone. Bluetooth just establishes the initial connection. Bluetooth High Speed is not widely deployed. People just don't want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't.  Bluetooth 3.0 or Bluetooth 4.0 does not imply High Speed support. Bluetooth 4.0 doesn't necessarily even imply backwards compatibility with Bluetooth 3.0 devices. iPhone 4S has hardware that supports High Speed, but the software only supports Bluetooth 4.0, not high speed.

For a lot more info, see http://chipscoop.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-bluetooth-smart.html

Comment: So I take it that no iPhones support Bluetooth High Speed?